# How to create a keypoint detection model for human with custom dataset

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a key-points detection model for human, as there are many pretrained networks available to generate key-points, but i want to practice myself to create a keypoint detection model with custom dataset, cant find anything in web if someone have some info's then please share.
I want more points specified to the human body, but to do so i need to create a custom model to generate such kind of key-points in human body, i checked some annotation tools but those annotation tool helps to adjust the points they have already specified when taking dataset like COCO etc, i think we cant add more points to the image. i just want to build a new model with custom key-points.
please share your views about my view on to the problem and please suggest some links if you have any idea about the same

Comment: may be this will help, which shows how to train custom landmark points on faces.  https://github.com/fiyero/pytorch_facial_keypoints/blob/master/pytorch_train_facial_keypoints_git.ipynb

Comment: They already have a dataset with them, i think my problem is the dataset itself, which means the human dataset with key-points coordinate values specified, if this condition is satisfied then only i could consider training the model to do so. I am trying to find a solution for estimating body measurement for cloth fitting. so i choose to create a key-point detection model and then finding the distance between corresponding points helps in estimating the specific body part size using 2 pics ,one front view and one side view image and with keypoints specified on them, don't know it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a detailed github repo [Custom Keypoint Detection](https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/Custom-keypoint-detection) for dataset preparation, model training and inference on **Centernet-hourglass104** keypoint detection model based on **Tensorflow Object detection API** with examples.

This could help you in training your keypoint detection model on custom dataset.

Any issues related to the project can be raised in the github itself and doubts can be cleared here.